# ¿Cómo permitir solo 1 checkbox en datagridview?

Tags: c#

Tengo dos `datagridview` en mi formulario pero solo quiero que se pueda escoger una fila, para ello tengo este código: `

```
private void grdTablas_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
if ((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(((sender as DataGridView).CurrentCell as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value))
    {
        // Maybe have a method which does the
        //loop and set value except for the current cell
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdTablas.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index != e.RowIndex)
            {
               grdTablas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = false;
                //row.Cells[columnIndex].Value = false;
            }
        }
    }
   }           
 }
```

El problema es que tengo dos iguales solo cambia el nombre del `datagrid`, y cuando elijo varios en el mismo datagrid si funciona, pero elijo otro del datagrid 2 y me quita el checkbox que tenia seleccionado en el datagrid 1

Comment: Acabo de crear un `Form` con dos `DataGridView` y les puse `CheckBox` a cada uno y sí selecciona todos sin problemas.

Comment: Yo quiero que solo se seleccione solo 1 por datagridview, y si selecciona otro se quite el que tenia seleccionado.

Comment: Okay, ya entiendo tu problema. Lo que podrías hacer es poner dos `Panel` y en cada uno meter un `DataGridView` y dentro de ellos poner `RadioButton` en vez de `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a aclarar que no se como funciona el `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` perfectamente pero puedo sugerirte esta forma de hacerlo.

Podrias guardar la instancia del `checkbox` seleccionado y cuando les des clic a otro checkbox desmarcas el checkbox que fue seleccionado previamente.

```
private DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkboxSeleccionado = null;
private void grdTablas_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

  // Verificamos que se haya seleccionado un checkbox previamente checkbox 
  // y que ese no sea el que seleccionado ahora para no desmarcarlo.
  if(checkboxSeleccionado != null && (sender == checkboxSeleccionado) == false)
  { 
    // como el valor no es null, entonces sí hay uno seleccionado, por lo que lo desmarcamos
    checkboxSeleccionado.Value = false;
  }

  // guardamos el checkbox seleccionado
  checkboxSeleccionado = sender as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

}
```

De esta manera solo habra un solo seleccionado siempre.